# TextView ellipsize not work inside RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I can't understand why my textview is not ellipsized. Thank you for any help.
I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dash_whiteplate"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/info_activity_list_item_height"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <RelativeLayout style="@style/ItemFlightRouteLayout" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/routImageTop"
            style="@style/ItemFlightRouteArrow"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_arrowup_normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/routAiroportFrom"
            style="@style/ItemFlightRouteAirportName"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/topDescription"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/routImageTop"
            android:textAppearance="@style/ItemFlightRouteAirportName"
            android:text="askdjflsfksdfasdfdfsfdsfsdfsfdsdfsfd" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/topDescription"
            style="@style/ItemFlightRouteDescriptionLayout" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/verticalDivider"
                style="@style/ItemFlightRouteSeparator"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_time" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/txt_time"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/verticalDivider2" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timeDep"
                    style="@style/ItemFlightRouteText"
                    android:textColor="@color/statusLanded" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/verticalDivider2"
                style="@style/ItemFlightRouteSeparator"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_gate" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/txt_gate"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desciptionTop"
                    style="@style/ItemFlightRouteText" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@color/grey" />

    <RelativeLayout style="@style/ItemFlightRouteLayout" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/routImageBottom"
            style="@style/ItemFlightRouteArrow"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_arrowdown_normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/routAiroportTo"
            style="@style/ItemFlightRouteAirportName"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bottomDescription"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/routImageBottom"
            android:textAppearance="@style/ItemFlightRouteAirportName" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomDescription"
            style="@style/ItemFlightRouteDescriptionLayout" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/verticalDivider3"
                style="@style/ItemFlightRouteSeparator"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_time2" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/txt_time2"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/verticalDivider4" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timeArr"
                    style="@style/ItemFlightRouteText" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/verticalDivider4"
                style="@style/ItemFlightRouteSeparator"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_gate2" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/txt_gate2"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desciptionBottom"
                    style="@style/ItemFlightRouteText" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and styles:

```
<style name="ItemFlightRouteLayout">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">0.5</item>
    <item name="android:weightSum">1.0</item>
</style>

<style name="ItemFlightRouteArrow">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentLeft">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerInParent">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
</style>

<style name="ItemFlightRouteAirportName">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>

<style name="ItemFlightRouteDescriptionLayout">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">right</item>
</style>

<style name="ItemFlightRouteSeparator">
    <item name="android:layout_width">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">22dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/grey</item>
</style>

<style name="ItemFlightRouteText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I've got it!
What I've done: moved routImageTop and routAiroportFrom to LinearLayout, aligned it at parent left and set `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/topDescription"`
Now it works.

Comment: Thanks this also helped me... android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"

Answer (score 0):

Add in your Xml

```
<item name="android:marqueeRepeatLimit">marquee_forever</item>
```

in Activity

```
your_textview.setSelected(true);
your_textview.setSingleLine(true);
your_textview.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
```

I think you can put these values in Xml too...

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

The TextView needs focus to make the marquee scroll in a TextView. Have you tried using either selected_state, requestFocus, or setSelected to set focus to the TextView?

[Make a Scrolling Marquee, using scrollHorizontally, in a TextView](http://androidsbs.blogspot.com/2013/12/androidellipsize-make-scrolling-marque.html)

[Deprecated: Make a Scrolling Marquee, using singleLine, in a TextView](http://androidsbs.blogspot.com/2013/11/deprecated-make-srolling-marquee-using.html)